# Ansible variables in template

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

```
template/file.cfg.j2
```

This template file will contain basic lines that will be shared between three boxes. There will be some differences in the lines that will be unique for each box. This is a value I wish to variable:ize.

```
set system user nsroot 546426471446579744 -encrypted
```

The 546... hash should now be in a `{{ }}` variable, as it will differ between the instances. `{{ item.hash}}`

I need an approach on how to set it up and structure, do I need `include_vars` etc.

**EDIT:** What I have:

`vars/vars.yml`

```
servers
   ns:
     - name: Copy hash
       hash: 187f637f107bf7265069ace04bf87fcd8e63923169a2c529a
```

`playbook.yml`

```
  tasks:
    - name: Variable:ize
      template: src=templates/template.j2 dest=/tmp mode=644 owner=root group=wheel
      with_items: servers[ansible_hostname]
```

Comment: you can define specific hardware variance in systems in a `host_vars` file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your inventory file you'll want to do something like this:

```
host1 nsroot_hash=12345
host2 nsroot_hash=54321
host3 nsroot_hash=24680
```

And then your template/file.cfg.j2 will look like this:

```
set system user nsroot {{ nsroot_hash }} -encrypted
```

Edit: You want the `hash` variable to be defined in your inventory file since you want a different value for each host that you're going to run this task against.  So your [inventory](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html) (host_vars) file should look something like this (I assume `ns` is the name of one of your servers):

```
ns hash=187f637f107bf7265069ace04bf87fcd8e63923169a2c529a
```

Then your playbook.yml would simply look something like this:

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Variable:ize
      template: src=templates/template.j2 dest=/tmp/template.txt mode=644 owner=root group=wheel
```

Note that you don't need the `with_items` statement.  In the above case, assuming that `ns` is the name of a host then this will create the file /tmp/template.txt with the templated text in it. (Note that `dest` is a path to a file, and not just a path to a directory.)

If you want to apply this task to multiple hosts then all you do is edit the inventory file as shown above:

```
ns hash=187f637f107bf7265069ace04bf87fcd8e63923169a2c529a
aa hash=aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
bb hash=bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
```

When you run the above playbook.yml file then it will apply the template to all three hosts, ns, aa, and bb, and put the proper hash value in the file on each host.

Comment: Your vars.yml file has a syntax error in it.  [yamllint](http://www.yamllint.com/) is a good resource for getting familiar with the syntax of yaml files. At the very least you need a ':' after the word 'servers', but you probably want that vars.yml file to be structured differently as well.  Take a look at my edits above.

Comment: That's fine thx. Although my template will be huge and contain other static hashes, IP's and hostnames. So I wouldn't want to store all that in the inventory file but have all variables in vars.yml. It will target 3 instances and they will have unique hashes, IP's and hostnames.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the host_vars (and group_vars) directory structure.  It lets you put variables in per-host (or per-group) files in a specified directory.  It's much easier to manage host & group variables that way. Ansibles [Best Practices](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_best_practices.html) document covers it briefly.

Comment: I have this working now. Although I don't know why I should have the hash in the inventory hosts file as well as in the host_vars/ns. It seems to only pick up the hash from my hosts inventory file. If I remove the line in hosts: 10.1.2.3 nsroot_hash=187f... it will generate an error: One or more undefined variables: 'nsroot_hash' is undefined.

Comment: You shouldn't need it in both.  If `host_vars/ns` isn't being recognized then you may not have it in the correct location.  It defaults to /etc/ansible/host_vars/ (assuming your inventory file is `/etc/ansible/hosts`) but if you're specifying an inventory file from a different location via the `-i` command line parameter then the host_vars directory will be looked for there.